# How to add text every 1 second to old text in TextView

Tags: android, loops, textview, handler

i'm trying to add text every 1sec to old text in `TextView` let me explain more

for example in first time i have in `TextView` this text :

Hello 1

after 1sec must be added to another text like this

Hello 1

Hello 2

and after 1sec

Hello 1

Hello 2

Hello 3

this is my code :

```
Texthack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hacktext);
    Handler Timer = new Handler();
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j<=1000 ;j++) {
        i++;
        final int finalI = i;
        Timer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Texthack.setText("Hello "+ finalI +"\n");
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use append instead of setText https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 0):

Now your replacing the current text by your new text. You have to change this line:

`Texthack.setText("Hello "+ finalI +"\n");`

To

`Texthack.append("Hello "+ finalI +"\n");`

Comment: Your usage of append is incorrect. I edited it to fix it. When you append you should only add the new strings you want to add without getting the old text first.

Comment: @KarimElGhandour Thanks ;) at first I was showing an example by including the current text while adding the new text. Then I changed it to `append` but completely forgot to remove it.